# Create clean/blank MacOS fs on MacOS or Linux

Tags: containers, macos

In developing/testing OSS libraries I can replicate a clean Linux fs using containers. However, if I want to test oss libs for MacOS end users, I seem to be in a bit of a quandary. Is there any way to create a clean fs on MacOS that I can test libraries with? Perhaps using `chroot`? Can someone explain exactly instead of just saying "use chroot"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can containerize MacOS, but you could create a Mac OS VM and snapshot it, that way you can easily restore to the same exact Mac OS version for each test.

Comment: a VM is a good idea, any more info on how to do?

Comment: Looks like these instructions to compile Swift code on Linux should suffice? https://www.raywenderlich.com/1448-introduction-to-open-source-swift-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell so far, the best way to replicate a clean MacOS fs on Linux is to use a VM. These instructions should suffice:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1448-introduction-to-open-source-swift-on-linux